# Why is my bitcoin wallet keep telling me: there was a problem sending your transaction uneconomical UTXO requested

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-wallet-app, btcguild, hitbtc

[image]
[image]

That is what I keep receiving when I try to sent my bitcoin to another wallet address ...

Comment: Which wallet software are you using? It would probably be best to direct this question towards their customer service department.

Comment: See comments to [Uneconomical UTXO requested](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/85164/13866)

Answer (score 1):

To state simply, you *don't have enough money* to send, your output was 4142 satoshi in the previous transaction but you need 22013 satoshi, try to find out if this is because of hidden tx fees or your trying to send from the wrong wallet/ transaction chain

Answer (score 0):

Many Bitcoin Wallets have complicated error states that don't clarify things for the end user. When sending BTC, there is a chance you could be spending an input that is a lower cost than the cost of sending the transaction. This is due to the fee market imposed by preventing the scaling of the block size. It seems you may have hit that error with your [Bitcoin Wallet](https://wallet.bitcoin.com). Best to get clarification from their support team.