# I want to transfer my bitcoin but i cannot

Tags: transactions

I want to transfer bitcoin to a wallet adress but when i send it gives me this error
There was a problem sending your transaction Uneconomical UTXO requested [type: 1 (limit 5643), txOut.val: 4123, required: 109544]
What it means and how can i send ?  Please help me thanks

Answer (score 2):

> **Uneconomical UTXO requested**

This usually means the amounts you are trying to send are so incredibly tiny that the transaction fees will cost more (perhaps much much more) than the amount being sent.

See [dust](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bitcoin-dust.asp)

See helpful comments to other similar unanswered questions:

- [cant send btc, Uneconomical UTXO requested](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/88200/13866)
- [Uneconomical UTXO requested](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/85164/13866)

Maybe its like using DHL or FedEx to send a small piece of a 1 paisa coin to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin is not meant for transactions in large scale. 
You need to set up a [Lightning-network](https://lnroute.com) for this.
It is the promised solution to the transaction prob.